# aspx reg expression validator: first character followed by optional second char

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, validation, character

I need to form a regular expression (reg ex) for an .aspx program that validates one character followed by optional characters.

The first character is more strict, not allowing hyphen or space.

I had

```
^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 -]{1,9}
```

which works, except there must be at least two characters (the limit is 9 chars total).

The .net code was as follows:

```
   controltovalidate="txt1" validationexpression="^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 -]{1,9}"></ASP:REGULAREXPRESSIONVALIDATOR>
```

[Since asking the question, I've found that simply changing {1,9} to {0,9} accomplishes what I need, but I am retaining the question as possibly useful to others, especially the answer below]

I read that

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9 -])?{1,9}
```

might work as I'm grouping the chars after the first with parens and using a "?" as optional.

However, I really need to know if this is correct syntax before I move this code to production.

Furthermore, it fails an online reg expression validator.

Does anyone know if this will work for an aspx reg expression validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following: `/^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9 -]){1,8}$/`

Working Demo @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rJ0cI8/1)

## Edit #1 (Explanation)

In your pattern `^[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9 -])?{1,9}` the **greedy quantifier** aka `{n,m}` is preceded by the **greedy quantifier** aka `?`, none of them are **quantifiable** tokens, So having a quantifier token preceded by another quantifier token is sematically incorrect.

In order to achieve your goal you must let that your second range of acceptable characters only allow **1** to **8** appearances: `(?:[A-Za-z0-9 -]){1,8}`

Comment: In my version of aspx, the above doesn't work, but I am assuming it is valid reg ex somewhere so I marked as answer.  It turns out that my version of visual studio (VS2013) will validate this if I open in browser and the expression in the comment below works for my needs.

Comment: "^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 -]{0,9}"

Comment: @JosephDoggie:  Could you please provide your .NET code that uses the regex?

Comment: @JosephDoggie: Just remove the slashes from the regex, you don't need those in asp.net (C#/VB). **^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9 -]){1,8}$**

Comment: controltovalidate="txt1" validationexpression="^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 -]{0,9}"></ASP:REGULAREXPRESSIONVALIDATOR>

Comment: @JosephDoggie:  ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9 -]){1,8}$" should do the job.